# phoneGap issues

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Guys I have this peace of code I'm using phonegap with jqueryMobile to develop cross platform apps.

The initialized function is called when the page loads
the alert start pops up

BUT function "populateDB" is never called, neither the success or the error methods are called

!!

```
function Initialize() 
        {
            alert("start");
            db = window.openDatabase("YahooMovies", "1.0", "Yahoo Movies", 200000); 
            db.transaction(populateDB, DB_Error, updateDb);
        }

        function populateDB(tx)
        {
            alert("initSql");
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblMovies');
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblMovies (Id unique, Title, EpisodeNum, PubDate, PoweredBy, VideoURL, ImageUrl, CategoryId, Restriction, keywords, Text, Adult, Actors, Director, Writer, Producer, Visitor, Album, Artist)');
        }
```

Comment: It workds perfectly on the browser
but gives this error only in the emulator

Comment: anything interesting in the DDMS log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No emulator will ever be able to perfectly articulate the actions of a device, especially if the two are based on different architectures. If you're talking about iOS emulation, believe me, an emulator's response should never be indicative of a device's response. iOS itself compiles for three different architectures: `armv6`, `armv7`, and `i386`.

That being said, if it is working on your device and not your emulator, do not fret. After all, it is the device that counts. No one will be using the application in an emulator except for you.

**EDIT:** Whoops, just saw that android tag. Same thing applies!

Answer (score 0):

Most Likely a typo in one of your Function Names - updateDb - Has a lowercase "b" while your other Vars have Caps.

This code works for me:

```
`function populateDB(tx)
 {
    alert("initSql");
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblMovies');
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblMovies (Id unique, Title, EpisodeNum,      PubDate, PoweredBy, VideoURL, ImageUrl, CategoryId, Restriction, keywords, Text, Adult,    Actors, Director, Writer, Producer, Visitor, Album, Artist)');
 }

 function DB_Error(tx)
 {
 alert("error");    
 }

 function updateDb(tx)
 {
 alert("updateDb");    
  }`
```